# Using Moment.js, the days field returning valid between 32 and 365, even when format specified to DD

Tags: momentjs

I am using a simple date validator:

```
function checkDate(testDate) {
    return moment(testDate, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a").isValid();
};
```

Entering a date, such as '09/32/2016 12:24 PM' is entered, the date is invalid.  However, change the days to '132', the method returns valid.  I have had to add my own days checker to insure a valid date.  Is there a way of configuring Moment.js to use 'DD' to insure a 2-digit date.  It seems to be assuming 'DDD' when it sees greater than 2 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strict parsing mode by adding `true` as a third parameter:

```
moment('09/132/2016 12:24 PM', "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a", true).isValid();
false
```

Note that this will require your string to be an exact match to the format. See the [parsing guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  I saw the Boolean, but missed the explanation in the docs.  Gotta slow down and RTFM better!